# If I install ubuntu on my USB will it affect my Hard Drive or will my Win 7 OS be lost?

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-drive, live-environment

If I install ubuntu on my USB will it affect my Hard Drive or will it delete my Win 7 OS?

And how do I make it to be a live USB so when I take out my USB I can boot Windows and When I plug it in I will get the bootup screen after I restart.

Comment: Ubuntu and Windows don't affect or harm each other no matter, whether they're on the same drive or not, unless you specifically tell them to. Since you're mentioning a USB installation, this may be of interest to you: [What would be the differences between a persistent USB Live Session and a installed Ubuntu in a USB drive?](/q/295701/175814)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First be sure of the drive that you want to install Ubuntu on, ie. `A:` drive, `B:` drive, `C:` drive, which ever one that is your flash drive that you want for installation. During the installation process, choose the custom installation option. At that point, you can install Ubuntu on the USB flash drive.

The reason for doing it this way is that you will have GRUB installed on your flash drive and still have BIOS on your Windows 7 computer. After the installation you can boot up on either operation system by pressing the <kbd>F12</kbd> button during  boot up. If you only want to use the Windows 7 during the boot up process than pressing the <kbd>F12</kbd> button is not necessary. With that said it is not a bad idea to remove the USB Ubuntu drive so that you do not accidentally have Windows format it.

The partition amount on the custom install is really up to you. The main thing is that GRUB and Ubuntu is installed on the same drive using the custom install option.

Comment: Your Windows 7 hard drive will be fine if you correctly follow the above procedure.

Comment: Ok So it will show the Ubuntu Option when I have my flash drive in. But there is no need to plug it in when I want to use Windows?!